# BrainFuck implementation problems:

Tags: c, brainfuck

I sat down and tried to implement the BrainFuck. The [syntax](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/) seems pretty simple. I am having trouble getting the silly thing to work. I've been at this a while; and I admit I need some sleep. Maybe that is all the problem is. The interpreter isn't outputting anything. I'm pretty sure the problem is a simple one; and I know I need to modularise some of the function calls after I get a better grasp of what direction I want this program to go. Why am I getting no output?

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include "list.h"

node file;
node flow;
node memm;

void init() {
    file.val = 1;
    file.next = 0;
    flow.val = 1;
    flow.next = 0;
    memm.val = 1;
    memm.next = 0;
}

int run = 1;
void quit(int val) {
    run = 0;
    while (file.next) pop(&file);
    while (flow.next) pop(&flow);
    while (memm.next) pop(&memm);
}

void doop() {
    switch (file.val++) {
        case '>':
            memm.val++;
            break;
        case '<':
            memm.val--;
            break;
        case '+':
            get(&memm, memm.val)->val++;
            break;
        case '-':
            get(&memm, memm.val)->val--;
            break;
        case '.':
            printf("c", get(&memm, memm.val)->val);
            fflush(stdout);
            break;
        case '[':
            if (!get(&memm, memm.val)->val)
                while (get(&file, file.val)->val != ']')
                    file.val++;
            else push(&flow, file.val);
        case ']':
            if (get(&memm, memm.val)->val)
                file.val = pop(&flow);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int flen, c, i, f_len;
    FILE *fh;
    char fh_name[] = "test";

    signal(SIGINT, quit);
    init();

    fh = fopen(fh_name, "r");
    while (run && (c = fgetc(fh)) != EOF)
        push(&file, c);
    fclose(fh);

    f_len = length(&file);
    while (file.val > 0 && file.val < f_len)
        doop();
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

`list.h`

```
struct node {
    int val;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node node;
int length(node *n);
void push(node *n, int i);
int pop(node *n);
node *get(node *n, int i);
```

`list.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "list.h"

int length(node *m) {
    int len = 0;
    while (m->next) {
        len++;
        m = m->next;
    }
    return len;
}

void push(node *n, int i) {
    node *m = n;
    while (m->next)
        m = m->next;
    m->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    m->next->val = i;
    m->next->next = 0;
}

int pop(node *n) {
    node *m = n;
    int i = length(n) - 1;
    while (i) {
        i--;
        m = m->next;
    }
    i = m->next->val;
    free(m->next);
    m->next = 0;
    return i;
}

node *get(node *n, int i) {
    node *m = n;
    while (i) {
        i--;
        if (!m->next)
            push(n, 0);
        m = m->next;
    }
    return m;
}
```

`test` is the BrainFuck "hello world"

```
Hello World program
>+++++++++[<++++++++>-]<.>+++++++[<++++>-]<+.+++++++..+++.[-]>++++++++[<++++>-]
<.#>+++++++++++[<+++++>-]<.>++++++++[<+++>-]<.+++.------.--------.[-]>++++++++[
<++++>-]<+.[-]++++++++++.
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. yes, i'm *still* at it right now. `gdb` and I are good friends

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi check that `fopen()` succeeded before attempting to read from the file, and also **The interpreter isn't outputting anything**, there is no interpreter involved.

Comment: @iharob the file is being read; I can read the file in reverse out of memory by popping all the `file` values. As for there being "no interpreter involved", I probably am using the incorrect term.

Comment: @MotokoKusanagi that is not a good reason to write unsafe code, you can get used to it.

Comment: I got it working. There were a miltitude of thing wrong with it: Missing `break`s, multiple logical errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
switch (file.val++) {
```

just can't be right. Currently it's just incrementing the first "val" of the file chain like the "mem.val++" below it.

I expect you'll need to get rid of the ++ on that line then do something about incrementing a pointer to an instruction rather than the instruction itself.

---

Your ']' instruction is wrong; you'll need to do the pop even if you've not going to go back.

---

Your '[' instruction is partly wrong. If the value starts at zero it will currently skip to the first ']' it finds not the matching ']'.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you need to sleep and also because your code is messy, I found this

```
printf("c", get(&memm, memm.val)->val);
```

it will print a `c` and that's all, it should be

```
printf("%c", get(&memm, memm.val)->val);
/*      ^ it's the format specifier for the argument */
```

**How did I find this so quickly?**

- Very simple, I enabled compiler warnings.

**BTW**: `get(&memm, memm.val)->val` is really bad style, but really bad.